# page nested 3 levels deep shows 404

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

I just created a page called Series at `/media/archive/series/`, parenting this new page under `/media/archive/`

The page at /media/archive works, but this new page, 3 levels off the root, shows a 404.

This is the first page I've nested this deeply. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I tried visiting the Permalinks page in admin to flush it, but that dind't fix it.

My Permalinks structure is set to `http://domain.ext/sample-post/`

Does anyone have any suggestions for me on this?

Answer (score 1):

This should not be a problem unless you've a same slug page / post in your TRASH somewhere. Check your Pages / Posts trash and see if you've "series" slug there?

If not, try creating another page and see if its just a matter of the page name / slug or its happening with all pages in 3rd level.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to check the trash for a duplicate slug. There wasn't one, so I created another page off the same parent, with a name I knew would be unique, and it too gets a 404. I should mention that the site is running on a Windows server. Not sure if that info helps. I'm also going to ask our IT dept if they can think of anything server related that would cause this.

Comment: I noticed this can also happen if any of the page ancestors is on the trash. +1